# Merge sort unexpected output in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

This is my code for merge sort , but this code outputs the wrong answer and i have checked several times but could not find out the reason for wrong output . I would be thankful if anyone can tell me why this is happening.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    void merge(int a[],int l,int m,int h){
        int n1=m-l+1;
        int n2=h-m;
        int L[n1],R[n2];
        int i,j,k;
        for( i=0;i<n1;i++){
            L[i]=a[l+i];
        }
        for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
            R[j]=a[m+1+j];
        }
        i=0;j=0;k=0;
        while(i<n1 && j<n2){
            if(L[i]<R[j]){
                a[k]=L[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                a[k]=R[j];
                j++;
            }

            k++;
        }
        while(i<n1){
            a[k]=L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<n2){
            a[k]=R[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }

    }
    void mergesort(int a[],int l,int h){
    if(l<h){
        int mid=l+(h-l)/2;
        mergesort(a,l,mid);
        mergesort(a,mid+1,h);
        merge(a,l,mid,h);
    }}
    void printArray(int A[], int size) 
    { 
        int i; 
        for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
            printf("%d ", A[i]); 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
    int main(){
       int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
        int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 

        printf("Given array is \n"); 
        printArray(arr, arr_size); 

        mergesort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
        printf("\nSorted array is \n"); 
        printArray(arr, arr_size); 
        return 0; 

    }
```

Input:

5

5 4 3 2 1

Output:

Given array is
5 4 3 2 1

Sorted array is
1 2 1 2 5

Comment: Did you debug your code with a debugger?

Comment: Suggestion: Name your variables! The computer does not work faster because you's saved a few letters when typing.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  I do not know how to debug i just compiled and ran this code.

Comment: Start your program in a debugger. Set a breakpoint and step through the code. What compiler do you use?

Comment: @Anonymous If you are going to write code, you should learn [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). I'd also advise being less compact with your code. Your code is so cryptic and condensed that it's not worth my time to read it.

Comment: When doing your merge, think about what elements you're trying to merge, and where those elements ultimately get copied to. (You're not copying them to the right place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `k` with the wrong value in `merge`.

`k=0;` would keep the pointer at the beginning, instead use `k=l;` to start copying the values to the current merge segment left bound.

```
void merge(int a[],int l,int m,int h){
    int n1=m-l+1;
    int n2=h-m;
    int L[n1],R[n2];
    int i,j,k;
    for( i=0;i<n1;i++){
        L[i]=a[l+i];
    }
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
        R[j]=a[m+1+j];
    }
    i=0;j=0;k=l;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2){
        if(L[i]<R[j]){
            a[k]=L[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            a[k]=R[j];
            j++;
        }

        k++;
    }
    while(i<n1){
        a[k]=L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<n2){
        a[k]=R[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
```